# Can't get layout in Android to function properly

Tags: java, android

I have a code in Android Studio that is supposed to display a list of details from my CRM. It is a very simple format to start off, but I can't get it to work. It is basically this:

```
                                     Product Name
Product Description
```

Then loop through like that for each product.

This is what it currently looks like:

[image: demo]

I also have a photo of the layout XML file I am using as a template:

[image: demo]

Here is the code I am using right now:

```
public class ShowPhotoshootList extends Activity {

    private TextView tvData;
    private Button Refresh;
    private TextView btnText;
    private ListView lvPhotoshoots;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_photoshoot_list);

        lvPhotoshoots = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvPhotoshoots);

        Refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
        btnText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);

        Refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JsonTask().execute(CRMURL Not Shown for Privacy);

            }
        });

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Photoshoots>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Refresh.setEnabled(false);
            btnText.setText("Loading");
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Photoshoots> doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);

                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();

                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);

                JSONObject responseJSON = JSONUtils.jsonObjectFromJSONForKey(parentObject, "response");
                if (responseJSON != null) {
                    JSONObject resultJSON = JSONUtils.jsonObjectFromJSONForKey(responseJSON, "result");
                    JSONObject contactsJSON = JSONUtils.jsonObjectFromJSONForKey(resultJSON, "Potentials");
                    JSONArray parentArray = contactsJSON.getJSONArray("row");

                    List<Photoshoots> photoshootsList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject mainObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray mainArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("FL");
                        Photoshoots photoshootSchedule = new Photoshoots();

                        for (int s = 1; s < mainArray.length(); s++) {
                            if (s == 1) {
                                JSONObject subObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(s);
                                Photoshoots PotentialName = new Photoshoots();
                                String val = subObject.getString("val");
                                String content = subObject.getString("content");
                                PotentialName.setPotentialName(val + ": " + content + "\n");
                                photoshootsList.add(PotentialName);

                            } else if (s == 2) {
                                JSONObject subObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(s);
                                Photoshoots Address = new Photoshoots();
                                String val = subObject.getString("val");
                                String content = subObject.getString("content");
                                Address.setAddress(val + ": " + content + "\n");
                                photoshootsList.add(Address);

                            } else if (s == 3) {
                                JSONObject subObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(s);
                                Photoshoots DateofShoot = new Photoshoots();
                                String val = subObject.getString("val");
                                String content = subObject.getString("content");
                                DateofShoot.setDateofShoot(content);
                                photoshootsList.add(DateofShoot);

                            }
                            photoshootsList.add(photoshootSchedule);

                        }

                    }

                    return photoshootsList;
                }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Photoshoots> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    btnText.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " Seconds");
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    btnText.setText("Refresh");
                    Refresh.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }.start();

            PhotoshootAdapter adapter = new PhotoshootAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, result);
            lvPhotoshoots.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
   }

    public class PhotoshootAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        private List<Photoshoots> photoshootsList;
        private int resource;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        public PhotoshootAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Photoshoots> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            photoshootsList = objects;
            this.resource = resource;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            }

            TextView tvPotential;
            TextView tvAddress;

            tvPotential = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPotential);
            tvAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);

            tvPotential.setText(photoshootsList.get(position).getPotentialName());
            tvAddress.setText(photoshootsList.get(position).getAddress());

            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
`
```

There is also another Java Class I am using for Getters/Setters, here is the code for that:

```
 public class Photoshoots {
    private String PotentialName;
    private String Address;
    private String DateofShoot;

    public String getDateofShoot() {
        return DateofShoot;
    }

    public void setDateofShoot(String dateofShoot) {
        DateofShoot = dateofShoot;
    }

    public String getPotentialName() {
        return PotentialName;
    }

    public void setPotentialName(String potentialName) {PotentialName = potentialName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post the layout file for your listview adapter? (R.layout.row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to fix the issue I had. Here is the code I have now

```
List<Photoshoots> photoshootsList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject mainObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray mainArray = mainObject.getJSONArray("FL");
                        Photoshoots photoshoot = new Photoshoots();


                    List<Photoshoots.potentialDetails> potentialDetails = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<Photoshoots.addressDetails> addressDetails = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<Photoshoots.dateDetails> dateDetails = new ArrayList<>();
                    List<Photoshoots.PotentialIDDetails> PotentialID = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int s = 0; s < mainArray.length(); s++) {
                            if (s == 1) {
                                JSONObject subObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(s);
                                Photoshoots.potentialDetails PotentialName = new Photoshoots.potentialDetails();
                                String val = subObject.getString("val");
                                String content = subObject.getString("content");
                                PotentialName.setPotentialName(content);
                                potentialDetails.add(PotentialName);


                            } else if (s == 2) {
                                JSONObject subObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(s);
                                Photoshoots.addressDetails Address = new Photoshoots.addressDetails();
                                String val = subObject.getString("val");
                                String content = subObject.getString("content");
                                Address.setAddress(val + ": " + content);
                                addressDetails.add(Address);

                            } else if (s == 3) {
                                JSONObject subObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(s);
                                Photoshoots.dateDetails DateofShoot = new Photoshoots.dateDetails();
                                String val = subObject.getString("val");
                                String content = subObject.getString("content");
                                DateofShoot.setDateofShoot(val + ": " + content);
                                dateDetails.add(DateofShoot);


                            }else if (s==0){
                                JSONObject subObject = mainArray.getJSONObject(s);
                                Photoshoots.PotentialIDDetails PotentialIDAdd = new Photoshoots.PotentialIDDetails();
                                String val = subObject.getString("val");
                                String content = subObject.getString("content");
                                PotentialIDAdd.setPotentialIDDetails(val + ": " + content);
                                PotentialID.add(PotentialIDAdd);

                            }
```

I set each object as it's own array and called each array at the end:

```
TextView tvPotential;
        TextView tvAddress;
        TextView tvDateofShoot;




        tvPotential = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPotential);
        tvAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        tvDateofShoot = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateofShoot);

        StringBuffer potentialBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(Photoshoots.potentialDetails details : photoshootsscheduleList.get(position).getPotentialDetails()){
            potentialBuffer.append(details.getPotentialName() + "\n");
          }
        StringBuffer addressBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(Photoshoots.addressDetails details : photoshootsscheduleList.get(position).getAddressDetails()){
            addressBuffer.append(details.getAddress() + "\n");
        }
        StringBuffer dateBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(Photoshoots.dateDetails details : photoshootsscheduleList.get(position).getDateDetails()){
            dateBuffer.append(details.getDateofShoot());
        }
        final StringBuffer potentialIDBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(Photoshoots.PotentialIDDetails details : photoshootsscheduleList.get(position).getPotentialIDDetails()){
            potentialIDBuffer.append(details.getPotentialIDDetails());
        }


        tvPotential.setText(potentialBuffer.toString());
        tvAddress.setText(addressBuffer.toString());
        tvDateofShoot.setText(dateBuffer.toString());
```

This managed to fix the issues I was having, and they are all working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `android:gravity="center"` attribute to your Large TextView (tvPotential).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tvPotential"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

         <!-- Here -->
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That did nothing, it looks exactly the same.

Comment: @UnlikelyLegendsMedia Are the gray bars in your first screenshot all part of the "Product Name"?

Comment: Yes, I have them blurred out because they contain personal information, but they are showing correct information.

Comment: @UnlikelyLegendsMedia Try adding an android:gravity="center" to the LinearLayout itself, then add android:layout_gravity="start" to the tvAddress TextView. If that doesn't work, then maybe try replacing the linear layout with a relative layout.